# Refering MongoDB indexes with find() / aggregate()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java

Is there any way to force a find() or aggregate() query to refer/see a particular existing index in MongoDB. I am asking about the the scenario when a collection has more than one compound indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [$hint](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/) is there for that. As mentioned in the documentation, you can use it like that:

```
db.users.find().hint( { age: 1 } )
```

What you put in argument is the definition of the index, and not its name. This query would force the use of the index on the `age` field. I'm not sure though whether it works for `aggreate()` call as well or not.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation does not support $hint. There is a open item in MongoDB 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7944